# missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file

Tags: compiler-errors, sbt, classpath

I have a multi module SBT project with modules named as commons, teradata, mysql, postgres etc.
commons as expected is a common module which every other module depends on.
I am getting the below error only for the module teradata when I compile it.
commons and the remaining modules compile fine without any error.

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HDFSUtil.class'.
[error] Could not access term hadoop in package org.apache,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'HDFSUtil.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HDFSUtil.class'.
[error] Could not access term io in value org.apache.hadoop,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'HDFSUtil.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.hadoop.
[error] two errors found
[error] (teradata/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Jul 29, 2016 7:48:50 PM
```

commons module depends the HDFS library with library dependency scope set as provided as shown below.

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.1" % "provided",
```

**if I remove the provided scope the above compile time error disappears.**

The teradata module itself doesn't have any dependency apart from unmanaged dependency on teradata jdbc and commons module.
I have tried removing my .sbt and .iv2 files and doing a clean build again but the error won't go away.
what could be possibly wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant bits from your sbt build files so that we can try to replicate and find the issue?